# Jquery index in relation to other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I was wondering if it possible to find the index of an element in relation to the number of elements with the same class, and if so how would I go about doing this?

So if I have the following...

```
<div class="container">
    <p>This is content 1</p>
    <p>This is content 2</p>
    <p>This is content 3</p>
</div>

    ...other HTML

<div class="container">
    <p>This is content 1</p>
    <p>This is content 2</p>
    <p>This is content 3</p>
</div>
```

And you click on an item in the first container it will return index 1, but if you click on an item in the second container it will return index 2 because it is the 2nd div with the class 'container'.

Is this possible? If so how can it be done?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: `$(this).parent().index()` should work... Add a +1 if you want 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.container p').on('click', function() {
      var index = $(this)   // point the clicked p
                      .parent()  // jump to .container parent
                      .index() +1;  // get index, As index() is zero based, so you can
                                    // add 1 to get 1,2,...
      alert( index );
    });
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.container p').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().index());
    });
});​
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/mG7yy/)